# How to remove mili seconds from '0' date formatting

Tags: c#, .net, datetime-format

I am trying to convert the DateTime to following Format.

2015-05-30T12:00:00+05:30

When I am trying with 'o' formatter getting the out put in following format,

```
string plannedStartTime = startTime.ToString("o");
```

> output:2015-06-12T16:54:47.3206929+05:30

I need to remove the mil seconds from that .

Not getting any formatters from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Any other Formatters?

Comment: Create a [custom format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

You can use a custom formatter:

```
string plannedStartTime = startTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz");
```

See also [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)